# Ubuntu Server Raid Install

Tags: installation, server, grub2, lvm, raid5

I am installing Ubuntu Server 13.04 on an ICH9R raid controller with 1tb of space (5 250gb Raid 5). Everything goes fine until the point of installing Grub. It will not install grub to anywhere but one of the partitions(dev/mapper/isw_digibbbgij_Volume0p1). After installing it to one of the partitions the machine will not boot.

My options are;

```
    dev/mapper/control
    dev/mapper/isw_digibbbgij_Volume0
    dev/mapper/isw_digibbbgij_Volume0p1
    dev/mapper/isw_digibbbgij_Volume0p2
    dev/mapper/isw_digibbbgij_Volume0p3
```

It will not let me select dev/mapper/isw_digibbbgij_Volume0, so I selected the first partition.

Furthermore the raid is still in initialize due to a limitation with this controler that requires a raid 5 with more than 4 drives to be initialized in the OS, which should happen as the OS is installed.

Am I selecting the wrong install point for grub? If so what should I enter?

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this, I found that instead of using `dev/mapper/*` you can use `dev/dm-0` which is to the right of the mapper identification. Once I did this it worked great. No need to install on different drives.